# Will my plan to convert a 240v range circuit to two 120v circuits work?

Tags: electrical, gas

I am switching my electric range to a gas range and need to convert the existing 240v outlet to 120v.  The existing line utilizes 6 gauge wire with a double (twin) 50 amp breaker.  I plan to switch out the 50 amp breaker with two 20 amp breakers, using only one for the range, then pigtail both ends of the 6 gauge wire with 12 gauge wire to connect to the breaker and neutral bus in the panel and the 20 amp outlet at the other end.  Would this work?  Are there any concerns having the 6 gauge wire delivering most of the run to the outlet?  Thank you.

Comment: Larger gauge wire is always allowed, code just mentions the minimum allowed.  The only concern is there are two extra electrical connections(pigtails), which okay as long as they are done right.

Comment: You'll need to put in a 20A 2-pole breaker to replace the 50A, not a pair of individual 20A breakers. You're turning the 240V range circuit into a 120V Multi-Wire-Branch-Circuit, so the breakers feeding it must be handle-tied (and I think common-trip).

Comment: The breakers need to be handle-tied (common trip not needed). **Grounds must be Real Grounds, not bootlegged from neutral**. So if this is a 3-wire range circuit you'll need to retrofit ground to it.  Remember, splicing to aluminum is no joke.  You'll need ILSCO Mac Block connectors for that (upside: they can mate to 1-4 copper wires).